# C generics: how to implement BST key range functions?

Tags: c, pointers, generics, binary-search-tree, valgrind

**I want to implement two generic functions in C that operate on a BST and store the keys of its nodes in a singly-linked list that is returned to the caller**. One function stores all the keys of the BST, and the other one stores only the keys within a given range. Both functions perform an "in order" visit, meaning that the keys are stored in ascending order with a tail insertion in the list.

Since I've found no pseudocode to look up to, I've tried to figure out a way to accomplish this but at the moment it doesn't work and Valgrind warns me of several issues, like "Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)". **There's probably something wrong with the way I'm trying to juggle the list around from one function to the other, or some misplaced malloc() or free()**.

Also I've got a question on how to improve the whole code: instead of using two different functions that are very similar but ultimately do different things, it could be great to use just one that does different things depending on the input that it receives. The range of keys that must be stored consists in a "low_key" and a "high_key", so that all the keys between the two are valid. **Since these two keys are pointers to void, if both of them are passed as NULL it could mean that I want to store all the keys of the BST**. Is this correct or could it lead to unexpected outcomes?

- `list_t` is a pointer to a node of the list (it points to a `node_t`);
- `node_t` is a node of the list and it points to a key field;
- `bst_t` is a pointer to the main BST structure, which points to the root node (which is a `bst_node_t`);
- `bst_node_t` is a node of the BST;
- `comparator_t` is a pointer to a function that compares generic data and is stored in the main BST structure; returns 1 if first element > second element, -1 otherwise and 0 if they're equal;
- `low_key` is the lower bound of the range of keys, `high_key` the upper bound.

**CODE FOR STORING ALL THE KEYS**

```
list_t bst_keys_all(const bst_t tree) 
{
    if (bst_is_empty(tree))
        return NULL;

    // pointer to head
    list_t list = malloc(sizeof(node_t));

    if (list == NULL)
        return NULL;

    // head passed as pointer to pointer to emulate pass by reference
    traverse1(tree->root, &list);
    return list;  
}

void traverse1(node_t *node, list_t *list)
{
    if (node == NULL)
        return;

    traverse1(node->left, list);
    append(node, list);
    traverse1(node->right, list);
}

void append(bst_node_t *tree_node, list_t *head)
{
    list_t new_node = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    list_t last_node = *head;

    new_node->key = tree_node->key;
    new_node->next = NULL;

    if (*head == NULL) {
        *head = new_node;
        return;
    }

    while (last_node != NULL) {
        last_node = last_node->next;
    }

    last_node->next = new_node;
    free(new_node);
    return;
}
```

**CODE FOR STORING ONLY THE KEYS WITHIN A RANGE**

```
list_t bst_keys_range(const bst_t tree, const void *low_key, const void *high_key)
{
    if (bst_is_empty(tree))
        return NULL;

    list_t list = malloc(sizeof(node_t));

    if (list == NULL)
        return NULL;

    // head of the list passed as pointer to pointer again
    // key_cmp is a field of the main bst structure that points to a comparator_t function
    traverse2(tree->root, &list, low_key, high_key, tree->key_cmp);
    return list;
}

void traverse2(node_t *node, list_t *list, const void *low_key, const void *high_key, comparator_t cmp)
{
    if (node == NULL)
        return;

    if (cmp(low_key, node->key) < 0) 
        traverse2(node->left, list, low_key, high_key, cmp);

    if (cmp(low_key, node->key) <= 0 && cmp(high_key, node->key) >= 0) 
        append(node, list); // it's the same function used in the code above

    if (cmp(high_key, node->key) > 0) 
        traverse2(node->right, list, low_key, high_key, cmp);
}
```

Comment: `list_t list = malloc(sizeof(node_t));` is suspicious as the relationship of  `list_t` and `node_t` is not defined in code.  Suggest `list_t list = malloc(sizeof *list);` and remove that uncertainly.

Comment: `list_t` is just an abbreviation for a pointer to a `node_t` (defined with typedef), and `node_t` is the bare struct for the nodes of the list. All the data types that I've mentioned are defined in a separate header file that is included in the source code.

Comment: Please read the site guidelines concerning help with debugging. You must provide a minimal but complete example. As it stands, I can't even try to compile and run your code.

Comment: Sorry but that would be kinda hard because the whole codebase consists in more than 800 lines of code split among 4 or 5 different files.